# Owner of php session folder keeps changing

Tags: php, nginx, yum

## Problem

Every few weeks, the php session folder of a machine changes to owner `apache` even though I'm using nginx. This breaks PHP applications, for example phpMyAdmin, with a `session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)`-Error.

I can fix it by manually issuing `sudo chown -R nginx /var/lib/php/session/`

## Environment

- Virtual Machine with CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708, yum-cron with automatic security update installation enabled
- EPEL-Repository installed
- nginx version: nginx/1.14.0
- php version: 7.0.29 (PHP-FPM)

## Additional Details

- This seems to break every few weeks, however I can't tell when exactly since we do not use this PMA on a daily basis. However, it broke this week, and in `/var/log/yum.log` I can see that nginx was updated this week:
  `Apr 18 04:35:53 Aktualisiert: nginx.x86_64 1:1.14.0-1.el7_4.ngx`
- I can not find any mention of the user `apache` in my `/etc/php.ini`.
- While it's broken, the folder permissions are:
  `drwxrwx---.  2 root apache   94 28. Mär 07:49 session`

## Question

Why would (automatic) nginx-updates change the owner of the php session folder, thus breaking my applications?

Comment: where did you get nginx from? EPEL shows `1:1.12.2-2.el7` for me. Otherwise, `rpm -ql ...` on packages and see if any own that directory, or look for package scripts that may fiddle with permissions. It could be something else, so you may need SystemTap or sysdig monitoring  on system calls involving that directory.

Comment: This machine is not under puppet, but history says I got it directly from my repos via `yum install nginx`. The session folder is not mentioned on `rpm -ql nginx`. Where would I go looking for these package scripts? Is that what SystemTap is for?

Comment: `rpm -q --scripts <pkgname>`. SystemTap or sysdig are completely different and would (with suitable code) allow you to log something when something touches `/var/lib/php/session`

Comment: @thrig, you were pointing me just in the right direction - the php-fpm package resets the ownership. I've created new folders, changed the config of php to use them and restored SELinux. Do you want to type up an answer so I can accept it, or shall I do it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several ways to approach this problem

## package search

If a package is suspected of causing some change, inspect the packages to see if any own the file in question; RPM contain a `%files` section that detail what files a given package is authoritative for. This can be queried for with `rpm -ql`. For example a brute force to find which package (if any) owns `/etc/passwd` might look like:

```
$ rpm -qa | while read p; do rpm -ql $p | grep -q /etc/passwd && echo $p; done
setup-2.8.71-9.el7.noarch
```

This method however will not find files that are indirectly modified by a package; RPM contain scripts that can carry out arbitrary actions (or call arbitrary other bits of code that carry out the change being search for). These scripts can be listed with `rpm -q --scripts` and then that code inspected. It may help to limit the search to only those packages recently installed (check the logs for which ones these are) as there may be a lot of code to look through.

## kernel debugging

The linux kernel offers various kernel-based debugging facilities that can be instructed to tell you if something touches a given file. With this method suitable code for `SystemTap` or `sysdig` or whatever would be setup, and then you would wait for that to tell you what process has modified the file. For example with `sysdig` if something is modifying a directory you are interested in:

```
# sysdig "fd.directory contains /var/lib/php"
```

should show details (which can be configured with the `-p` flag) on system calls involving that directory. This command will need to be left running somewhere, possibly in a `tmux` session or as a custom service so that it starts automatically until the offending code can be found. (Also you may need to limit the debug output, as kernel debugging may produce copious amounts of information if the search is too broad and the command left running for long periods of time.)

Comment: Thanks again. In my specific case, it was the php-fpm package which simply expects php to be run with user apache and resets the folders owner on update. I fixed this by creating new session folders and declaring them in the config file.